# Book of drug interactions

Tags: medications

Where can I find full list of drug _ drug interaction & adverse reaction, apart from pdr.net, I mean to say in a book form. What books of medical science contain these information? Please name a few. I have read Lippincott's Pharmacology but I did not find any list.

Answer (score 2):

Definitive manuals, or textbooks for drug interactions tend not to be published on their own any longer, due to their need to be constantly updated, and having been superseded by better ways to search for the information required, in a digital format. OR - they are tremendously expensive, like [this](https://www.pharmpress.com/product/9780857113474/stockley). Otherwise, drug interactions and adverse reactions are integrated into clinical pharmacology textbooks such as Rang and Dale.

Other study books, such as [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Top-100-Drugs-Pharmacology-Prescribing/dp/070207442X/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=prescribing&qid=1596656972&sr=8-1), do have commonly prescribed drugs with major interactions listed per each drugs.

In the United Kingdom, we tend to use the British National Formulary (BNF) which is given to all doctors in a paper-copy, but is also online - [here](https://bnf.nice.org.uk/) which has a fully searchable interactions section. It can be bought in paper copy [here](https://www.amazon.co.uk/British-National-Formulary-September-2020/dp/0857113690/ref=sr_1_1?dchild=1&keywords=formulary&qid=1596657102&sr=8-1) - but it's not a good study book, it's a reference for working prescribers.

https://www.drugs.com/ is reliable, an USA-based, with an interactions - but is again a website.

If you want to let us know what specifically you are revising for, or what you need it for - perhaps we'll be able to point you to a more specific book. :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the most well-known books dedicated to drug interactions and serving as a comprehensive reference for this topic specifically is [Stockley's Drug Interactions](https://www.pharmpress.com/product/9780857113474/stockley). You can find a sample chapter [here](https://www.pharmpress.com/files/docs/Stockleys_Drug_Interactions_11_Sample.pdf).

Highly recommended!